# phpunit: How do I pass values between tests?

Tags: class, phpunit

I'm really running into a brick wall with this. How do you pass class values between tests in phpunit?

Test 1 -> sets value,

Test 2 -> reads value

Here is my code:

```
class JsonRpcBitcoinTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp(){
        global $configRpcUser, $configRpcPass, $configRpcHost, $configRpcPort;

        $this->bitcoindConn = new JsonRpcBitcoin($configRpcUser, $configRpcPass, $configRpcHost, $configRpcPort);
        $this->blockHash = '';
    }

    /**
    * @depends testCanAuthenticateToBitcoindWithGoodCred
    */
    public function testCmdGetBlockHash()
    {   
        $result = (array)json_decode($this->bitcoindConn->getblockhash(20));
        $this->blockHash = $result['result'];
        $this->assertNotNull($result['result']);
    }

    /**
    * @depends testCmdGetBlockHash
    */
    public function testCmdGetBlock()
    {   
        $result = (array)json_decode($this->bitcoindConn->getblock($this->blockHash));
        $this->assertEquals($result['error'], $this->blockHash);
    }
}
```

`testCmdGetBlock()` is not getting the value of `$this->blockHash` that should be set in `testCmdGetBlockHash()`.

Help in understanding what is wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `setUp()` method is always called before tests, so even if you set up a dependency between two tests, any variables set in `setUp()` will be overwritten. The way PHPUnit data passing works is from the return value of one test to the parameter of the other:

```
class JsonRpcBitcoinTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        global $configRpcUser, $configRpcPass, $configRpcHost, $configRpcPort;

        $this->bitcoindConn = new JsonRpcBitcoin($configRpcUser, $configRpcPass, $configRpcHost, $configRpcPort);
        $this->blockHash = '';
    }


    public function testCmdGetBlockHash()
    {   
        $result = (array)json_decode($this->bitcoindConn->getblockhash(20));
        $this->assertNotNull($result['result']);

        return $result['result']; // the block hash
    }


    /**
     * @depends testCmdGetBlockHash
     */
    public function testCmdGetBlock($blockHash) // return value from above method
    {   
        $result = (array)json_decode($this->bitcoindConn->getblock($blockHash));
        $this->assertEquals($result['error'], $blockHash);
    }
}
```

So if you need to save more state between tests, return more data in that method. I would guess that the reason PHPUnit makes this annoying is to discourage dependent tests.

[See the official documentation for details](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much, I have no idea how I did not pick up on that.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this answer. Wish there was a way to declare a mutable variable that can be shared between tests, but this seems elegant enough.

Comment: You might highlight that you're referring to "@depends" annotation, it took me a while before figuring out... Nice answer anyway

Comment: What about sharing data between two different tests like UserTest.php and DeviceTest.php is that possible?

Answer (score 9):

You can use a static variable within a function...
PHP annoyingly shares static variables of class methods with all the instances... But in this cas it can help :p

```
protected function &getSharedVar()
{
    static $value = null;
    return $value;
}

...

public function testTest1()
{
    $value = &$this->getSharedVar();

    $value = 'Hello Test 2';
}


public function testTest2()
{
    $value = &$this->getSharedVar();

    // $value should be ok
}
```

NB: this is NOT the good way but it helps if you need some data in all your tests...

Comment: Very helpfull when you need get or set configuration for all tests in the class. There is no method that is called with session context like *setUpPage* only once before all tests in the class. Em i right?

Comment: Atually i've found *public static function setUpBeforeClass()* but this one is called before test class is instantiated.

Comment: "PHP annoyingly shares static variables of class methods with all the instances" - that ist the whole point of static variables! They exist for exactly this purpose, to share values between all instances of a class. I do not get why this can be annoying, if you do not want that, then do not use static variables. Please read the documentation about static variables in PHP.

Comment: static variables in non static methods could have been instance scope centric instead of class scope centric. IMO more OOP friendly and more usefull.

Comment: Thank you for stating this.  Very frustrating when you don't know this.

Comment: Just wanted to touch on the static variable solution.  This is a good answer, static member variables are accessible across test method calls while scope can be limited.  For static variables inside functions, this is not instance dependent and functions just like static memory elsewhere in the language.  [Example #5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) covers this point.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use static variables.

Here is an example (for Symfony 4 functional tests):

```
namespace App\Tests\Controller\Api;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Hautelook\AliceBundle\PhpUnit\RefreshDatabaseTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\AcceptHeader;

class BasicApiTest extends WebTestCase
{
    // This trait provided by HautelookAliceBundle will take care of refreshing the database content to a known state before each test
    use RefreshDatabaseTrait;

    private $client = null;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private const APP_TOKEN = 'token-for-tests';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $app_user__email = 'tester+api+01@localhost';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private static $app_user__pass = 'tester+app+01+password';

    /**
     * @var null|string
     */
    private static $app_user__access_token = null;

    public function test__Authentication__Login()
    {
        $this->client->request(
            Request::METHOD_POST,
            '/api/login',
            [],
            [],
            [
                'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
                'HTTP_App-Token' => self::APP_TOKEN
            ],
            '{"user":"'.static::$app_user__email.'","pass":"'.static::$app_user__pass.'"}'
        );
        $response = $this->client->getResponse();

        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $response->getStatusCode());

        $content_type = AcceptHeader::fromString($response->headers->get('Content-Type'));
        $this->assertTrue($content_type->has('application/json'));

        $responseData = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('token', $responseData);

        $this->static = static::$app_user__access_token = $responseData['token'];
    }

    /**
     * @depends test__Authentication__Login
     */
    public function test__SomeOtherTest()
    {
        $this->client->request(
            Request::METHOD_GET,
            '/api/some_endpoint',
            [],
            [],
            [
                'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
                'HTTP_App-Token' => self::APP_TOKEN,
                'HTTP_Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . static::$app_user__access_token
            ],
            '{"user":"'.static::$app_user__email.'","pass":"'.static::$app_user__pass.'"}'
        );
        $response = $this->client->getResponse();

        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $response->getStatusCode());

        $content_type = AcceptHeader::fromString($response->headers->get('Content-Type'));
        $this->assertTrue($content_type->has('application/json'));
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static variable using the method setUpBeforeClass:

```
protected static $sharedId;

public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
{
    self::$sharedId = random_int(100,10000);
}
```

And access it in you tests like this:

```
public function testCreateLocation() {
    echo 'Shared variable = ' . self::$sharedId;
    // Use the variable in your test code and asserts...

}
```

/The Schwartz

Answer (score 0):

Another (simpler) example using static variables as pointed out by Boštjan Biber:

```
class ClientTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    protected $client;
    protected static $testClient;

    // Before a test method is run, a template method called setUp() is invoked.
    public function setUp() :void
    {
        $this->client = new \Application\models\Clients;
    }

    public function testInsertCustomer()
    {
        $testclient = array(
            'name' => 'Test Client',
            'responsible' => 'Responsible Test',
            'payment' => 'Test payment',
            'email' => 'Test Email',
            'phone' => '123-456-789'
        );
        $this->assertTrue($this->customer->insertCustomer($CustomerTest));
    }

    public function testGetCustomers()
    {
        $this->assertIsArray($this->customer->getCustomers());
        $this->assertNotEmpty($this->customer->getCustomers());
        // Save test client for other methods
        $clients = $this->client->getClients();
        static::$testCustomer = end($customers);
    }

    public function testGetClient()
    {
        $this->assertIsArray($this->customer->getCustomer(static::$customerTest['customer_id']));
        $this->assertNotEmpty($this->customer->getCustomer(static::$customerTest['customer_id']));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please repost this in English? It's hard for me to follow.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me perfectly fine across all tests: $this->varablename

```
class SignupTest extends TestCase
{
    private $testemail = "registerunittest@company.com";
    private $testpassword = "Mypassword";
    public $testcustomerid = 123;
    private $testcountrycode = "+1";
    private $testphone = "5005550000";

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown(): void 
    {
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testSignup()
    {
        $this->assertEquals("5005550000", $this->testphone;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's scenario that there must be 2 tests, 1 that sets the value and 1 that gets the value. You've just got 1 test that gets.